# PThread Creation and Termination

Tags: c, pthreads

I am new to **Pthread programing using c**
I happen to take up the following code from the web

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_THREADS     5
void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
  long tid;
  tid = (long)threadid;
  printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
   long t;
    for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
       printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
        if (rc)
         {
     printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n",  rc);    
          exit(-1);
          }
    }

       /* Last thing that main() should do */
       pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The output received varies every time I run the above code.
Any reasons for the error?

Comment: you r printing thread Id here which will be different for each thread..

Comment: @Naresh: The code prints the value of `t` as assigned in the `for`-loop in `main()`.

Comment: The only error in the code is that it most likely misses to prototype `exit()`.

Comment: Thank you I could solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what error in your program. It can perform perfectly.when thread is created, its running time is out off your control, you don't know which time it locates, this depends your OS. So every output is different

Comment: Is there a way to keep a watch on running time                                                                                                          In main: creating thread 0
In main: creating thread 1
In main: creating thread 2
In main: creating thread 3
In main: creating thread 4
This message of amin function is always in the order of threads 1 to 4 but what varies in the output is the output for the threads in hello world.

Comment: I think this is because when thread 1-4 are created, the main thread is occuping cpu, so you can see the output "In main: creating thread1-4" in order. But in theory the output would vary, when you create a thread, it can occpied the cpu and completed its task right now, in other way it could need a little time to wait cpu. So your cofusion is not a problem, just because your machine don't run in your thinking way. Your think is just a possiblity, but not all.